# Stock quantity magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want product current stock. That's why I have used below code. But every time I got the initial stock. I have changed the stock manually from magento 2 admin. But it shows the same.

```
$stockManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistry')->getStockItem($item->getId());
        print_r($stockManager->getData());

{
item_id: "8",
product_id: "8",
stock_id: "1",
qty: "50.0000",
min_qty: "0.0000",
use_config_min_qty: "1",
is_qty_decimal: "0",
backorders: "0",
use_config_backorders: "1",
min_sale_qty: "1.0000",
use_config_min_sale_qty: "1",
max_sale_qty: "10000.0000",
use_config_max_sale_qty: "1",
is_in_stock: "1",
low_stock_date: "",
notify_stock_qty: "1.0000",
use_config_notify_stock_qty: "1",
manage_stock: "1",
use_config_manage_stock: "1",
stock_status_changed_auto: "0",
use_config_qty_increments: "1",
qty_increments: "1.0000",
use_config_enable_qty_inc: "1",
enable_qty_increments: "0",
is_decimal_divided: "0",
website_id: "0",
type_id: "simple"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way in product details

```
<?php 
// get qty product
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$productTypeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
if ($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
    $usedProducts = $productTypeInstance->getUsedProducts($product);
    $count = 0; 
    foreach ($usedProducts  as $child) { 
        $productStockObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($child->getId());
        round($count+=$productStockObj->getData('qty'));
    } 
    echo $count;
} else {
    $productStockObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($product->getId());
    echo round($productStockObj->getData('qty'));
}
echo __('pcs');
```